# Удаление слов из строки

Tags: c++, c

Добрый день)) Уже второй день пытаюсь написать эту программку, но у меня ничего не получается((( Помогите пожалуйста. Есть условие, которое находит самое длинное слово в предложение. Теперь необходимо удалить слова, которые состоят из латинских букв. (нельзя использовать string и тому подобные)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char str[80];
    cout << "Enter string: ";
    cin.getline(str,80);

    int i;

        //Выводим само длинно слово

    int lenght = strlen(str);


    int maxLen = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        if (str[i] != ' '){
            count += 1;
        } else {
            if (count > maxLen) {
                maxLen = count;
                index = i - count;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (count > maxLen) {
        maxLen = count;
        index = i - count;
    }
    maxLen += index;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = index; i < maxLen; i++){

        //putchar(str[i]);
        cout << str[i];
    }
        printf("\n");

        bracket(str);
```

Вот я что-то пыталась (n-раз) написать, но оно как всегда не работает)

```
int temp =0;
        for(int i=0; i < lenght; i++){
         if (((str[i]>='a')&&(str[i]<='z'))||((str[i]>='A')&&(str[i]<='Z'))){
            temp++;
         } else 
            str[i-temp] = str[i];
         lenght-=temp;
    }
    cout << lenght;
    for(int i=0;i<lenght;i++)
        cout << str[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а регулярки можно использовать???

Comment: *"нельзя использовать string и тому подобные"* -- чему подобные? Поконкретней можно, что именно нельзя использовать?

Comment: @Alex.B да можно

Comment: @PinkTux Ну желательно сделать максимально просто, без использования готовых функций

Comment: Допускаю фразу *нельзя использовать <нечто>* без обоснования причин только в вопросах с меткой [tag:соревнование].

Comment: Вообще тут 2 никак не связанных друг с другом задачи. Если вы будете удалять слова во время поиска самых длинных, то найденое самое длинное вы в конечном итоге просто потеряете. Если, конечно, не сохранять его отдельно где-то дополнительно. Но почему-то кажется, что это не то, что требуется :)

Comment: @PinkTux требуется просто удалять слова из латинских букв, без использования функции string

Comment: @ДашаНовикова  Удаляемые слова должны целиком состоять из латинских букв, или достаточно в слове присутствия одной латинской буквы?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ну я думаю никто не будет писать в одном слове разные буквы, так что наверное целиком

Comment: @ДашаНовикова Тогда на самом деле следует, что достаточно одной латинской буквы в слове.

Answer (score 3):

Я не знаю, что такое "функция string", поэтому вот обе части задания отдельно, с минимальным использованием библиотечных функций. Код немного избыточен для наглядности. При удалении слов (вторая часть) пробелы и знаки препинания остаются на своих местах. Обработка цифр не предусмотрена.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[] =
        "someяяя string with longюю, longest, short and shortest words";
    char *s = str;
    char *longest_ptr = s;
    size_t longest_len = 0;
    char *word_ptr;
    size_t word_len;

    while( *s ) {
        /* пропускаем пробелы и знаки препинания */
        while( *s && ( isspace( *s ) || ispunct( *s ) ) ) {
            s++;
        }

        /* ищем самое длинное слово */
        word_len = 0;
        word_ptr = s;
        while( *s && !isspace( *s ) && !ispunct( *s ) ) {
            s++;
            word_len++;
        }

        if( word_len > longest_len ) {
            longest_len = word_len;
            longest_ptr = word_ptr;
        }
    }

    /* выводим самое длинное слово */
    printf( "longest word (%zu chars): ", longest_len );
    while( longest_len-- ) {
        putchar( *longest_ptr++ );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    /* теперь ищем слова с латиницей */
    s = str;
    while( *s ) {
        while( *s && ( isspace( *s ) || ispunct( *s ) ) ) {
            s++;
        }

        longest_len = 0; /* длина текущего слова */
        word_len    = 0; /* количество латинских букв в нём */
        word_ptr    = s;

        while( *s && !isspace( *s ) && !ispunct( *s ) ) {
            if( ( *s >= 'a' && *s <= 'z' ) || ( *s >= 'A' && *s <= 'Z' ) ) {
                word_len++;
            }
            longest_len++;
            s++;
        }

        /* слово только из латиницы, двигаем оставшуюся строку на его место */
        if( word_len == longest_len ) {
            /*
             * было бы логичней:
             * memmove( word_ptr, s, strlen( s ) + 1 );
             * но раз задание для мазохистов...
             */
            word_len = 0;
            while( *s ) {
                word_ptr[word_len++] = *s++;
            }
            word_ptr[word_len] = 0;
            s = word_ptr;
        }
    }

    printf( "string without latin-only words: '%s'\n", str );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #include <string.h> без этой библиотеки)

Comment: @ДашаНовикова, чтобы убрать зависимость от `string.h`  вам нужно переписать одну строку: `memmove( word_ptr, s, strlen( s ) + 1 );` . Дерзайте :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно совсем топорно проверить по кодам символов и если встретили хоть один, то удалить всю входную строку, возможно это не совсем корректно.

```
int check_str(char * str)
{ //Большие 65-90 строчные 97-122 в dec ASCII
     int check = 0;
     for(int i =0; i<sizeof(check);++i)
        {
          check= static_cast<int>(str[i]);
               if(check>=65 || check<=90 || check>=97 || check<=122)
                    str="";

}
```

Comment: Приведенный вами фрагмент кода не имеет смысла.:)

Comment: ну да там косяк)

Answer (score 1):

Мои три копейки.:)

Хотел бы отметить, что совершенно не обязательно, что буквы латинского алфавита, следуют друг за другом без пропусков кодов. Поэтому в общем случае нельзя просто проверять диапазон `['a', 'z']` или `['A', 'Z']`

В предложенной ниже программе удаляются слова, которые содержат по крайней мере одну латинскую букву. Вместе с такими словами удаляются все другие символы, которые следуют за удаляемым словом и находятся перед следующим словом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    const char *latin = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const size_t N = 100;
    char s[N];

    std::cout << "Enter a sentence: ";

    if ( std::cin.getline( s, sizeof( s ) ) )
    {
        size_t n = std::strlen( s ) + 1;

        for ( char *p = s; *p;  )
        {
            while ( std::ispunct( ( unsigned char )*p ) || 
                    std::isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;

            char *first = p;

            bool has_latin = false;

            while ( *p && !std::ispunct( ( unsigned char )*p ) &&
                          !std::isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) )
            { 
                if ( !has_latin )
                {
                    has_latin = 
                    std::strchr( latin, 
                                 std::toupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) != nullptr;
                }                       
                ++p;
            }

            if ( has_latin )
            {
                while ( std::ispunct( ( unsigned char )*p ) || 
                        std::isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;

                std::memmove( first, p, n - ( p - s ) );

                n -= p - first;

                p = first;
            }               
        }

        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Диалог с программой может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Enter a sentence: один one два two три three четыре four пять five
один два три четыре пять
```